# How to update table automatically in MYSQL using TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table in mysql database where I am calculating New Owed Balcance based on the interest + amount borrowed... I want it to be that when the interest is altered the new owed balace changes I am using Triggers but it does not seem to update it when the interest changes

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER updateloan BEFORE INSERT ON loan
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.app_amnt_owed = NEW.app_intrst +NEW. app_ln_amnt;
  END;
|
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Comment: good point @Devart, so how would I go about doin this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateloan_update
  BEFORE UPDATE ON loan
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.app_amnt_owed = NEW.app_intrst + NEW.app_ln_amnt;
```