# Update SQL table usign data from another table + custom text

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

Need a solution for the following situation:
I need to update T1, column Email
with the following data:
id from T1 + @test.com

Result that I need should look like this = 1234@test.com,
That number must be an ID from T1 + @test.com

For example:

```
table 1 = customer  
COLUMNS = ID, Email,
```

Need to update the Email column.
Results should look like this:

```
   ID Email   
    1  1@test.com       
    2  2@test.com       
    3  3@test.com
```

I'm doing this on an existing tables, not creating them. 
tnx in advance

Comment: Tag dbms used. Add sample table data (both tables), and the expected result.

Comment: use triggers and write procedure in database.
[something similar here check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510896/how-to-update-table-automatically-in-mysql-using-trigger)

Comment: I just saw your edits. Great! But please add the RDBMS into your tags (Oracle, SQL Server, other?) and the version number (e.g. sql-server-2012). After your edits I think my answer is exactly what you are looking for. Did you check this?

Comment: From your last sentence I get the feeling, that you misunderstood the `CREATE`... This is nothing you have to do, just a test scenarion to play with. The only part you really need is `UPDATE T1 SET eMail= CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@test.com'` . Just replace the "T1" with your actual table's name and the column names with the names of your actual columns.

Comment: Yup, that's it!
Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (ID INT, OtherData VARCHAR(100),eMail VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO T1(id,OtherData) VALUES(1,'Row 1'),(2,'Row 2'),(3, 'Row 3');

SELECT * FROM T1;

UPDATE T1 SET eMail= CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@test.com'

SELECT * FROM T1;

--Clean Up
DROP TABLE T1;
```

The result:

```
ID  OtherData   eMail
1   Row 1       1@test.com
2   Row 2       2@test.com
3   Row 3       3@test.com
```

Comment: I actually remember this question :D Thank you a lot, with a bit of delay!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE T1 SET  
[Email] = T2.ID + '@test.com'  
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1  
ON T2.[key_column] = T1.[foreign_key_column];
```

Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

use triggers

triggers are used to insert or update the data when something is changed(inserted, updated and deleted).
You can use like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event ON table_name
```

`FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
 ...
 END;`

You can write your insertion code in between BEGIN and END.